# Latin for a "control knob"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, neologism

What is an appropriate Latin word for a **knob** that controls something else, such as a volume control knob, a light dimmer, the tuning control on a radio, the temperature control knob on a space heater, etc.?

It doesn't need to be Classical Latin, of course. I figure there must be some precedent in New Latin. Or coin a word in Latin style if you need to. (I *suspect* that control knobs were in use in Ancient Greece and even earlier, but I don't know.)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [*bulla*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dbulla), which is used for a door-knob?

Comment: I don't have an answer. One thing this question brought to my mind is tuning pins/pegs on instruments, which seem somewhat similar in function, but I don't know what Latin words are used to refer to those.

Comment: @sumelic, That's a nice idea. For what it's worth, the Latin Wikipedia page for [Testudo (instrumentum musicum)](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testudo_(instrumentum_musicum)) refers to them as 'manubria vel turbines ob intendendos nervos'; but I'm not sure what evidence exists for those terms (and I have an automatic distrust of any source that starts with wik(i)). If that page is correct, though, manubrium or turbo would work. I have to say, my first thought was bulla (as suggested by brianpck) or umbilicus.

Comment: @brianpck Surely there's no doubt about _bulla_? Smith & Hall offer several interesting possibilties, but _bulla_ is the top one. Why don't you make it a proper answer?

Comment: Another possible source of precedent: medieval and renaissance writings about pipe organs.
Hmm, [Theophilus](https://books.google.com/books?id=wo4EAAAAYAAJ&q=knob#v=snippet&q=knob)…

Answer (score 2):

One option is [*bulla*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dbulla), which can be used to refer to a door-knob, as in the below quote from Plautus:

> jussine in splendorem dari bullas has foribus nostris? Plautus, As., 2:4:20

It has a range of other, quite different meanings, like "bubble" and even "amulet," but with proper context it should do the trick!